# Swing, Java, How to close() anything jFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

There is a changePassword Frame.
Since the window for each user is different, password change uses one frame. (changePW jFrame)

Because the password change may be canceled or it may be wrong, the parent window that opened the password change window did not disappear until the change was completely completed. So I did not dispose ().

The problem is,
If the login () -> userX (another frame by the logged in person) -> changePW () is executed sequentially, the password change is normally successful.

How can I dispose () all of the parent frames with the corresponding changePW () after successfully changing the password? (Do not use exit.)

Comment: 1) Those windows should not **be** JFrames. They should be JDialogs for starters.

Comment: 2) for another for better questions, create and post a valid [mcve]. This might make your question easier to understand.

Comment: [How to use dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels oh, got it. i will useJDialog!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JFrames always bind to basic operating system side primitives.  When they close, you need to clean up the native OS side of things.  This is why closing them they way you are describing isn't a great idea.

Instead, configure the way the frame should close.  Usually it is one of

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
--or--
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

And when you decide to close the `JFrame`, create an event that Swing will process that indicates the window in question is closing, and send it to the dispatcher.

```
WindowEvent closeEvent = new WindowEvent(myFrame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
myFrame.dispatchEvent(closeEvent);
```

This will leverage the Swing / AWT event processing code to close the window, guaranteeing all the correct closing methods are called.

Comment: oh Thx!, i got it!!